# Using Class to create TkInter Countdown timer

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a coundown timer using Tkinter in Python. The code works fine when I run without using Class but when I introduce class, for some reason the code is not running: the reset button does not make the first cell 00 and the 00 is not there by default to get started with. Thanks for the help!

```
#**--This is working--*
#Practicisng above Code#
#-------------------------------------------

import time
from tkinter import *

WinD = Tk()

WinD.geometry("300x350")
WinD.title("Time Counter")

Hours = StringVar()


Hours.set("00")


hoursEntry = Entry(WinD, width=3, font=("Cambria",18,""),
                 textvariable=Hours)
hoursEntry.place(x=80,y=20)


def reset():
    #change the value of global variable
#     global count
#     count=1
    Hours.set("00")
    
         
        
btn = Button(WinD, text='Reset', bd='5',
             command= reset)
btn.place(x = 70,y = 120)

WinD.mainloop()
```

```
#**--This is not Working--**


#My Stopwatch Project
#importing req. modules
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time
global count

class Stopwatch():
    def __init__(self):
        #Create object of Tkinter, providing geometry and title
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Stop Watch")
        self.root.geometry("600x200")
        
        #Declaration of variables
        self.hour = StringVar()
        
        #Set the default value to 0 
        self.hour.set = ("00")
        
        #Use of Entry class to take inputs from the user
        self.hourEntry = Entry(self.root, width = 3, font = ("Arial", 18, ""), textvariable=self.hour)
        self.hourEntry.place(x=80, y=20)

        self.bt3 = Button(self.root, text = "Reset", command = self.reset, font=("Times", 12, "bold"), bg=("#DE1738"), bd=5)
        self.bt3.place(x=320, y=100)

        self.root.mainloop()    
      
    def reset(self):
        #change the value of global variable
        self.hour.set = ("00")
     
a = Stopwatch()
```

Comment: Shouldn't `self.hour.set = ("00")` be `self.hour.set("00")`?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).